# ownership of hard drive recoveery of files Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

Here is the issue. I have an old laptop that died that was running xp. I now have a win 7 laptop. I need to get the files off the old drive. Win 7 will not let me take ownership of the drive. I can runn the comand prompt in regular mode and do a dir on the drive that shows up as Q: drive in regular mode. I gives me the volume as c and the serial number. I can not take ownership in regular mode with the comand prompt or other means. Microsoft site says use safe mode with networking. So I go to safe mode the drive shows up as G: in safe mode. I use the comand prompt Takeown /f G: and get the device is not ready error. I am at a loss. All I want is to retrieve my files from this drive. Any ideas or sugestions. I don't see how you can dir and get some info in one mode and not acces it in another. I have to get ownership and permissions fixed to get in the drive to get my files.
Thanks in advance. I might add that I am using a usb3.0 to ide/sata cable adapter. Software came with the device but I can't make heads or tails out of the manual to know if any of the software can help me. The soft ware is PCClone Ex lite, and Clone Drive Soft ware

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Linux live CD to retrieve the files. Most recent Linux distributions have NTFS support, and are handy for doing other recovery tasks. Try Ubuntu.